# Parse string for text between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a string of html text stored in a variable:

```
var msg = '<div class="title">Alert</div><div class="message">New user just joined</div>'
```

I would like to know how I can filter out "New user just joined" from the above variable in jQuery/Javascript so that I can set the document title to just the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
document.title = $(msg).filter("div.message").text();
```

Note that if the message changes to be wrapped in an element, you'll need to replace `filter` with `children`.

**EDIT**: It looks like the `div` that you want is nested in other element(s).
If so, you can do it like this:

```
document.title = $("div.message", msg).text();
```

---

Explanation:  `$('<div>a</div><div>b</div>')` creates a jQuery object holding two different `<div>` elements.  You can find the one you're looking for by calling the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function, which finds mathcing elements that are in the jQuery object that you call it on.  (Not their children)

`$('<p><div>a</div><div>b</div><p>')` creates a jQuery object holding a single `<p>` element, and that `<p>` element contains two `<div>` elements as children.  Calling `$('selector', 'html')` will find all descendants of the elements in the HTML that match the selector.  (But it won't return the root element(s))

Comment: My apologies.  I replaced it with filter and it works perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack and not very clean, but it should work:

1. add a div node and set its html to your text message,
2. get the text of the added element and store it in a variable
3. destroy the node
4. set the title with the contents of the variable in step 2